# Why doesn't a disabled input field get sent in the request body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I have the following form:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/updatedetails" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrfToken}}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fieldUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" disabled class="form-control" id="fieldUsername" name="username">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- more content -->
```

The value of the username input text field is set by jQuery during page load:

```
$('#fieldUsername').val(username);
```

The jQuery seems to work, as I can see the username field into the text field although it is disabled.

My question is, when I post the form why is the username not included in the request body ? All the fields are included. Does it mean that disabled fields are not included in the request body ?

Comment: Change disabled to readonly

Answer (score 4):

This field is not sent as it's disabled.

You should change it to `readonly`.

Regards

Comment: you are right!!

Comment: Dude - can you delete your answer so i can delete my question ? Everyone is giving me -1!